# Visual Code won't kill the server after I stop or restart project

Tags: .net, linux, visual-studio-code, process, blazor

I'm running a blazor project on Visual Code 1.72.2 in Debian 11.

**launch.json:**

```
  {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "type": "blazorwasm",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/MyApp/", 
    "url": "http://localhost:5123"
   }
```

**launchsettings.json:**

```
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5123",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

After I stop the project and try to run it again, I'm getting either:

> Could not copy "/somePath/obj/Debug/net5.0/apphost" to
> "bin/Debug/net5.0/MyApp". Beginning retry 3 in 1000ms. Text file busy
> : '/somePath/bin/Debug/net5.0/MyApp'  [/somePath/MyApp.csproj]

Or

> The port is 5123 already in use (something like that).

I have to manually search for the process using the port and kill it.

What might be happening?

Comment: issue tickets with similar but not the same error messages: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/7157, https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5630, https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli/issues/168